# Convert compile-time-constant int to compile-time-constant String in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, compile-time-constant

I have an annotation that requires a compile-time-constant String and I wanted to initialize it with a compile-time-constant int from one of the libraries I'm using. So what I ended up doing was something like this:

```
public class LibraryClass {
    public static int CONSTANT_INT = 0; //Where 0 could be whatever
}

public class MyClass {
    private static final String CONSTANT_STRING = "" + LibraryClass.CONSTANT_INT;

    @AnnotationThatNeedsString(CONSTANT_STRING)
    public void myMethod() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of converting primitives to compile-time-constant Strings than using `"" + PRIMITIVE_TO_CONVERT`? Some way to "cast" a primitive to String? Because doing it like this feels a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current solution is best, as you correctly determined that Annotations need "compile-time constant" values. `"" + INT_VALUE` is at least better than creating redundancy by repeating the value from the library, but as a String (`"23"`), and it's a "nice" feature of the Java language to determine your solution as compile-time constant.

If you are able to, you could of course also change the Annotation to take an int as value parameter, as suggested in another answer (but I assume the Annotation comes from a library as well?).

Answer (score 0):

Try using String.valueOf(LibraryClass.CONSTANT_INT);

Comment: But that cannot be used directly within the annotation, only in CONSTANT_STRING initialization.

Comment: Is "private static final String CONSTANT_STRING = String.valueOf(LibraryClass.CONSTANT_INT);" not applicable?

Comment: Yes, that will work and is a correct answer. But I think the question creator asked for something like @AnnotationThatNeedsString(someCleverCastOf(CONSTANT_INT)).

Comment: No, I have to correct myself. The String is no longer compile-time constant then, and so your solution won't work - you can't use the constant within an annotation then.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

- make @AnnotationThatNeedsString take an int or
- make the constant a String. You can parse it as an int at runtime.

e.g.

```
public static int CONSTANT_INT = Integer.parseInt(CONSTANT_STRING);
```